# call requires permission which may be rejected by user?

Tags: android, google-maps

```
    private void getCurrentLocation()
    {
        mMap.clear();

        Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);
        if (location != null)
        {
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
            moveMap();
        }


    }
```

I new to Android. I followed some links to find my current location on google maps. I wrote the permissions in manifest file but the error message ask the permission I don't know how to solve that. I have tried searching but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: You need to implement runtime permissions and ask the user for ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION or ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or both.

Comment: how to do that.

Comment: If you are having trouble handling the runtime permissions,  have a look at my library: https://github.com/nabinbhandari/Android-Permissions

Comment: The is your starting point https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html to get yourself acquainted with the Runtime Permissions model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I wrote the permissions in `manifest` file but the error message asks the permission I don't know how to solve that

You need to  [**ask run time permission**](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

**Because of** Beginning in **Android 6.0 (API level 23)**, users grant permissions to apps while the app is running, not when they install the app.

**CODE**

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSION_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
  }
```

Comment: I tried this code the error message shows cannot resolve the symbol MY_PERMISSION_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION

Comment: MY_PERMISSION_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION is an integer where you can give any value.

Try adding like this at top of your code.

int MY_PERMISSION_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION=100;

Comment: if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSION_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
        }
        Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);
        if (location != null)
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
            moveMap();